# how to log client real ip and also CDN ip?

Tags: nginx, cdn, cloudflare, real-ip

I'm using cloudflare for my website.

The issue I got is, after I enabled realip module on nginx, all CDN ips are replaced to user's realip. Then when I check the nginx log, I can't find out whether user is connecting via CDN or connection directly to server.

Below is my configuration:

```
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
...
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

....
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
```

Is there any way I can keep both realip and CDN IPs?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from: [Including the original visitor IP in your logs](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170786)

> You can include the variables `$http_cf_connecting_ip` and `$http_x_forwarded_for` in the `log_format` directive.

If you want both the CDN IP and the `CF-Connecting-IP` don't use the `real_ip_header` and add `$http_cf_connecting_ip` to your `log_format`:

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $http_cf_connecting_ip ...'
```